# Javascript function and web service call synchronization

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services

Hi i have this code in page_load event on aspx page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            FillSomeDropDownLists();
        }

        EnableExportButton(false);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Page.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]) && Page.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "true")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "Show", "ShowPopup();", true);

            if (CallToWebService(Convert.ToInt32(Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"]), 1))
            {
                SomeOtherCallToWebService();
                Global.ShowMessage(this.Page, StringConstants.SUCCESS_TRANSACTION_TITLE);
            }
            else
            {
                Global.ShowMessage(this.Page, StringConstants.FAIL_TRANSACTION_TITLE);
            }

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "Hide", "HidePopup();", true);
        }
    }
```

I would like to show a javascript popup, then do webservice related stuff, and then hide the popup. That is how I coded it.

But in page execution I get call to webservices first, and then shows and hides the popup. Showing and hiding the popup is so fast that it seems nothing happens.

Is there solution to get what I want?

Comment: You can use setTimeout() method of javascript to call method after some time, there is no other way to solve your problem

Comment: In reality you should do most of this client side using JS/jQuery, what you have at the moment is super ugly. In JS show a div, then fire an ajax call to a handler, get the handler to call the web service, then when that has completed get the handler to return something to the client and then use JS to hide the div

Comment: Yes. this can also possible. do all work by JQuery on client side